# Will Soyuz TMA-16M have the most experienced crew?

Tags: iss, soyuz-spacecraft, future-missions

I was looking at the names of the crew for Soyuz TMA-16M (for the year long expedition) and I was thinking "wow that's an experienced crew!".

[image]

I looked up their combined experience and it shows as:

- [Gennady
  Padalka](http://www.spacefacts.de/bios/cosmonauts/english/padalka_gennadi.htm)
  710.265
- [Scott Kelly](http://www.spacefacts.de/english/bio_ast.htm) 180.077
- [Mikhail Kornienko](http://www.spacefacts.de/english/bio_cosm.htm)
  176.055

Total 1121.0342 days

Now, I guess I could go through every spaceflight shown on http://www.spacefacts.de/english/flights.htm and compute the total experience, but does anyone know if I'm right?

Comment: How would you like this compared with crews that have more than 3 people on them?  Like when there was a crew of 13?  Or are you only asking about Soyuz crews?

Comment: Yes, I wondered that also; but I was not meaning experience at ISS which arrived in several craft. Shuttle crew could be as large as 7 and soyuz 3; I actually did wonder if these three had more experience than any previous launch craft.

Comment: Fyi,  STS-61a had a crew of 8.

Comment: You could count experience differently as well. Number of days in space is useful experience for a long duration mission, but when you're launching I would count number of launches as more useful experience. Figuring out which mission had the highest "average launches per crew member" could be easy: find the people with the records then look at the crew of their last flight.

Answer (score 6):

I've crunched the numbers and can answer; my gut feeling was good, and in all 299 manned launches, no crew has a greater combined amount of time in space. My top 10 crew experience table is:

1. [Soyuz TMA-05M](http://www.spacefacts.de/mission/english/soyuz-tma-05m.htm) - 723.009 days : 3 Crew
2. [Soyuz TM-31](http://www.spacefacts.de/mission/english/soyuz-tm31.htm) - 680.813 days : 3 Crew
3. [STS-102](http://www.spacefacts.de/mission/english/sts-102.htm) - 651.844 days : 7 Crew
4. [Soyuz TMA-6](http://www.spacefacts.de/mission/english/soyuz-tma-6.htm) - 646.175 days : 3 Crew
5. [STS-134](http://www.spacefacts.de/mission/english/sts-134.htm) - 635.706 days : 6 Crew
6. [Soyuz TMA-01M](http://www.spacefacts.de/mission/english/soyuz-tma-01m.htm) - 630.625 days : 3 Crew
7. [Soyuz TMA-3](http://www.spacefacts.de/mission/english/soyuz-tma-3.htm) - 602.949 days : 3 Crew
8. [Soyuz TMA-04M](http://www.spacefacts.de/mission/english/soyuz-tma-04m.htm) - 598.083 days : 3 Crew
9. [STS-88](http://www.spacefacts.de/mission/english/sts-88.htm) - 572.844 days : 6 Crew
10. [Soyuz TM-33](http://www.spacefacts.de/mission/english/soyuz-tm33.htm) - 561.703 days : 3 crew

The growth in spaceflight experience per launch can be illustrated on this graph:

[image: Spaceflight hours versus time]

@Nickolai raised an interesting point; what happens if you measure number of previous launches averaged by crew size, you get the following experience rankings:

1. [Soyuz TMA-3](http://www.spacefacts.de/mission/english/soyuz-tma-03.htm) - 9 launches : 3 Crew (3.00)
2. [Soyuz TM-21](http://www.spacefacts.de/mission/english/soyuz-tm21.htm) - 8 launches : 3 crew (2.67)
3. [Soyuz TM-31](http://www.spacefacts.de/mission/english/soyuz-tm31.htm) - 8 launches : 3 crew (2.67)
4. [Soyuz TMA-11M](http://www.spacefacts.de/mission/english/soyuz-tma-11m.htm) - 8 launches : 3 crew (2.67)
5. [Soyuz TMA-16M](http://www.spacefacts.de/mission/english/soyuz-tma-16m.htm) - 8 launches : 3 crew (2.67)
6. [STS-80](http://www.spacefacts.de/mission/english/sts-80.htm) - 13 launches : 5 crew (2.60)
7. [STS-103](http://www.spacefacts.de/mission/english/sts-103.htm) - 18 launches : 7 crew (2.57)
8. [Soyuz T-13](http://www.spacefacts.de/mission/english/soyuz-t13.htm) - 5 launches : 2 crew (2.50)
9. [STS-79](http://www.spacefacts.de/mission/english/sts-79.htm) - 15 launches : 6 crew (2.50)
10. [STS-88](http://www.spacefacts.de/mission/english/sts-88.htm) - 15 launches : 6 crew (2.50)

The growth is launch experience per launch can be shown in the following graph:

[image: Launch experience versus time]

So, we can conclude,  the TMA-16M crew are the most experienced by space experience but amongst the most experienced by launch counts.

Comment: The answer has been updated to include all 299 manned launches. Took a while to tabulate all the data. The information on launch experience was previously incorrect.